# Nestead control in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have situation where I am having Repeater  in repeater i having 
radiobutton list which have static values
and I want another Text area inside 
now once i will bind data to my repeater on condition i want to to deside
to show Radio button list(Static) or Text Area
I am clueless now

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_Questions" runat="server"> <%--OnItemDataBound="rpt_Questions_ItemDataBound"--%>
            <ItemTemplate>

                <div><span class="presenter"><%# Eval("QuestionText") %></span></div>
                <asp:Label ID="lblQID" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ItemID") %>' />
                <div>
                    <ul class="clearfix">

                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtAnswers" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem>Not At all</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Fine</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Average</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Good</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Very Much</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine"/>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </Repeater>
```

Comment: Do you want to show either The Radiobuttons or the TextArea (Textbox), Depending on something in the code ?

Comment: yes absolutly depending on something show either text box or text are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put both of them in their own Panels,  pnlRadio, pnlText:

```
 <ul class="clearfix">
<asp:Panel id="pnlRadio" runat="server">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtAnswers" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                        <asp:ListItem>Not At all</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Fine</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Average</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Good</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Very Much</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
  </asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel id="pnlText" runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine"/>
                </ul>
```

re-enable the onItemDataBound and then

```
protected void rpt_Questions_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
      DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

      Panel pnlRadio = e.Item.FindControl("pnlRadio") as Panel;
      Panel pnlText= e.Item.FindControl("pnlText") as Panel;

if(drv["questionType"].ToString()=="choice") //or however you distinguish between the two
{ pnlRadio.Visible = True; pnlText.Visible = False;}
else
{ pnlRadio.Visible = False; pnlText.Visible = True;
```

Comment: thanks buddy it worked for me

Comment: Guys please make note , above code will create Radio ButtonList and TextBox double time  for number values will be there in your repeater